# Add the current project to the python path with Komodo Edit

Tags: python, intellisense, komodo, pythonpath, komodoedit

Ive been using komodo edit recently to go through a few django tutorials, and ive been impressed with the level of code completion it provides for the framework.

However what i really want it to do is provide code completion for the current project, so in effect my own views, models etc. would work in the same way as the framework itself.

Is there a way to temporarily modify the python path on a per project basis to get code completion of my current project?

NB: Im not sure whether this is a Stack Overflow or a Super User question, feel free to correct me.

Comment: I get code completion with my current project now, so could you explain what is happening? One thing that might help is sticking an empty "__init__.py" file into your package dirs.

Comment: I get code completion for the standard django library (so i can write `django.whatever` and get associated classes). However i cant seem to get my own project to do the same, so i cant do `myproject.views/models/urls/forms/whatever` it doesnt seem to recognise them.

Comment: Posting in the Komodo support forum may get more attention, http://community.activestate.com/forums/komodo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set per-project Python paths in `Project [Menu] -> Properties -> Languages -> Python -> Additional Python Import Directories`. See [the official documentation](http://docs.activestate.com/komodo/6.0/prefs.html#Python) for more details.