# komodo edit won't recognize python packages on script execution but recognizes them in auto-complete

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, module, komodoedit

I am trying to setup Komodo edit to run Python scripts on a new Mac running Mavericks. I installed the ActiveState version of Python (ActivePython 2.7.5.6) and some necessary packages to:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

To install the packages I used pip (pip install module) if it was possible. Otherwise I would use setup_tools, and the python setup script if the first two didn't work.

Komodo Edit's autocomplete also recognizes the packages (e.g. bitarray, Pycluster) and I can run the scripts using these packages from the terminal; however, when I execute the Python interpreter from Komodo Edit I get the following:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stevensteinway/Desktop/t-02.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bitarray
ImportError: No module named bitarray`

Under Preferences --> Python I've imported specific directories and this still doesn't solve the issue:

```
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitarray`
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how it could be fixed?

Thank you,

Steve

@martineau

I included the follow code:

`import sys
print sys.path`

and got this output:

`'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']`

The last folder is this: `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`

but I think it should be this:

‘/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages’

I entered it through the Komodo edit GUI (Preferences --> Languages --> Python) and the path I included is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages` seems to be truncated. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Near the top of your script `print sys.path` and see if the folder of what you're trying to import is one of the entries in the list.

Comment: Hi @martineau I commented above regarding the output from `print sys.path`. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Try adding a `sys.path.append('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages')` before the `import` statement(s) and see if that helps. `sys.path` is Python's search path for modules. You might also need another explicit one for `'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bitarray'`

Comment: I added that statement right after `import sys`
and right before `import bitarray` and it added the folder but I still get the same error. 

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stevensteinway/Desktop/t-02.py", line 4, in <module>
    import bitarray
ImportError: No module named bitarray`

Comment: Have you checked to make sure there's a `bitarray` somewhere in the `site-pa‌​ckages` folder (either a `bitarray.py`, a `bitarray` subfolder, for a shared-library with that name)?

Comment: The only one I can think of is [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html?highlight=PYTHONPATH#envvar-PYTHONPATH). Perhaps you should contact ActiveState's customer support.

Comment: So it seems like Python 2.7 is installed in 2 locations on my hard drive: 

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

and

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`

The first location has a subfolder called **site-packages**. The second doesn't. Could this be the issue?

Comment: `Could this be the issue?` -- most definitely.

Comment: Ok, do you have any idea why it would be installed in two places? I'm thinking Komodo might be confusing the two folders. I am going to contact ActiveState

Comment: It's probably because of the mixture of installation methods you used coupled with the fact that OS X comes with its own version of Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add the current project to the python path with Komodo Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284767/add-the-current-project-to-the-python-path-with-komodo-edit)

Answer (score 0):

The site-packages folder that you're looking for is not under '/System', it's under '/Library'.  Try what @martineau said but remove '/System' from the path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/p‌​ython2.7/site-packages')
# cross fingers
import bitarray
```